# Kepler Memory Usage

Tags: java

I am using Kepler 2.3 and it looks like my Kepler got killed when I tried to launch it on a cluster machine. The default heap space alloted to kepler is 512m. Is there any way that we can increase the heap size.

Thanks!

Comment: If you run that application with a shortcut like: `java -jar xxx.jar` you can add the `-Xmx1000m` option to increase the heap space to 1,000MB for example. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: I am running it on a linux machine as : java -Xmx1024m -classpath build-area/lib/ant.jar:kepler.jar org.kepler.build.runner.Kepler . but still when I execute this, it shows JVM Memory = 5m 512m.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the minimum memory allotted to Kepler which is by default 5m. Open memory.xml file which is present in KeplerData/kepler.modules/build-area/settings/memory.xml and edit 5m line (5m to some greater value, say 50m) and make sure that much RAM is available in your machine. Save the file and start Kepler again. During start up you can see the change in a stdout msg:
Kepler.run going to run.setMain(org.kepler.Kepler)
JVM Memory = 50m 512m

Hope it solves your problem.